# front end radio custom taxonomy with custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, front-end

Hi my good friends I need your help better than losing my mind, first I have to thank "Stephen Harris" for his [good article](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/how-to-use-radio-buttons-with-taxonomies/) ,

-second: After a lot of searching I still don't know how to inject a custom taxonomy to a custom post type
Here is my code:

```
  $post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
    'post_author' => $user_id,
    'post_title' => $post_title,
    'post_content' => $post_content,
    'post_category' =>   array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
    'tax_input' => array('offer' => $terms),
    'tags_input' => array($tags),
    'post_type' => 'classified',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
        ));

update_post_meta($post_id,'$term->term_id',$taxonomy,true);
```

and

```
   <?php
    //Set up the taxonomy object and get terms  
    $taxonomy = 'offer';
    $tax = get_taxonomy($taxonomy); //This is the taxonomy object  

    $name = 'tax_input[' . $taxonomy . ']';

    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => 0));
    $postterms = get_the_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy);
    $current = ($postterms ? array_pop($postterms) : false);
    $current = ($current ? $current->term_id : 0);
    ?>
    <!-- Display taxonomy terms -->  
    <div id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>-all" class="tabs-panel">  
        <ul id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>checklist" class="list:<?php echo $taxonomy ?> categorychecklist form-no-clear">  
            <?php
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $id = $taxonomy . '-' . $term->term_id;
                echo "<li id='$id'><label class='selectit'>";
                echo "<input type='radio' id='in-$id' name='{$name}'" . checked($current, $term->term_id, false) . "value='$term->term_id' />$term->name<br />";
                echo "</label></li>";
            }
            ?>  
        </ul>  
    </div>
```

What do I miss, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't show if and how you set `$terms` other then that its seems ok, just try to wrap it in an array and you should check if its set first, so try this:

```
$new_post = array(
    'post_author' => $user_id,
    'post_title' => $post_title,
    'post_content' => $post_content,
    'post_category' =>   array($_POST['cat']),
    'tags_input' => array($tags),
    'post_type' => 'classified',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
));
if (isset($_POST['tax_input']['offer'])
$new_post['tax_input'] array('offer' => (array)$_POST['tax_input']['offer']);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```